# Azure Timer Trigger Function Not Visible in Azure after Deployment from VS Code

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have followed the Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators#deploy-the-project-to-azure) twice, once for an HTTP Triggered Function, and I went through them again for a Timer Triggered function. On the second time through I did all of the same steps from the documentation, just using a Timer Triggered function.

When I deploy the HTTP trigger function after successfully testing locally, it appears as a function in my Azure Function App.

When I deploy the Timer Trigger function after successfully testing locally, it does NOT appear as a function in my Azure Function App.

I have been through this documentation multiple times and am doing everything it says, but cannot successfully deploy a timer-triggered function to Azure.

Deploying Timer Trigger function:
[image: Deployment]

Function does not appear in portal or function app:
[image: Missing function]

Answer (score 1):

the same is happening to me using python azure functions v2, deploying from github actions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).